# Cannot specify 'externalId' for a CustomField of type Text for entity Knowledge__kav

Tags: knowledge, externalid, lightning-knowledge

Why can't we create Custom ExternalId field on Knowledge?

We need to automate migration of related junction object which have Knowledge__kav as a parent.

Usually we just use bulk upsert, but if we can't set ExternalId, this means we need explicit Ids of Knowledge__kav records which we don't know until we load them into database.

It is not available from UI and when we try to set it through deployment it fails with an error

`Cannot specify 'externalId' for a CustomField of type Text for entity Knowledge__kav`

[image]